# What could cause random 1074 shutdown calls?

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I have a fairly new desktop computer I built in december. RTX 3090 GPU, i9-10850K CPU, SF 750W PSU, 32GB RAM, Windows 10.

I play quite a lot of games, and among them one specific game (Spiritfarer) causes my computer to properly shut down after a random time span - so far ranging from 5 minutes to about 8 hours.

My GPU and CPU temperatures and loads are fine so far as I can see, and I can run way more demanding games in top quality 120fps with no issue whatsoever, but this one acts up. My drivers are all up-to-date.

The event viewer system log shows this message (latest to date) - ID 1074 :

```
Le processus C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shutdown.exe (PC) a lancé l'arrêt de l’ordinateur PC pour l’utilisateur AUTORITE NT\Système pour la raison suivante : Aucun titre à cette raison n’a pu être trouvé
  Code : 0x800000ff
  Type d’extinction : s’arrêter.
 Commentaire :
```

Apparently it is a 32-bit app that initiates the shutdown, but the game is 64 bits. I've been scratching my head over this and questioning the developers, but we can't seem to figure it out. I do not believe it is a hardware problem, and I doubt the game simply initiates shutdowns randomly.

What could be happening ?

Comment: The 80000000 part means it was planned. The FF part probably means no reason given as it is common to use FF or FFFF as not set.

Comment: Is there a way to know what planned it, and when it was planned ?

Comment: Take ownership of shutdown.exe. Give yourself permissions. Rename it. Copy notepad or something that stays open to shutdown.exe. When notepad pops up open Task Manager and it parent should be shown on the Processes tab. **As admin** `takeown /f C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shutdown.exe`, `icacls C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shutdown.exe /grant Administrator:(F)`. PS many programs are 32 bit as it uses less memory than a 64 bit version.

Comment: I made a save of shutdown.exe and replaced it with notepad.exe called shutdown.exe. If I double click it it doesn't open notepad. Unsure it'll work.

Comment: Make sure in Explorer you have show extensions turned on or in a command prompt `dir C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\shutdown*.*` Known extensions display is turned off by default.